# How to call a multiple html pages one by one on clicking the respective content in nav bar?

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying table of content in nav bar and while clicking on that item i want to display the HTML which is already linked to that item.In my case while clicking on that item new page is opening in other tab I want to open new HTML in same page.

This is my code.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width: 250px;background:  beige;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <h2 class="fm_title" id="toc" style="font-size: 18px;">TABLE OF CONTENTS</h2>
<p class="toc_noindent" id="fm_2"><a href="Pub21749_data_01_prelims.html#fm2">Sections Affected by 2017 Legislation</a></p>
<p class="toc_noindent" id="fm_3"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~01.html#fm3">California Legal Guidelines</a></p>
<p class="toc_center" id="ma_1"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~03.html#main_1"><span class="bold">VEHICLE CODE</span></a></p>
<p class="toc_noindent" id="ma_2"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~03.html#main_2"><span class="bold">General Provisions, &#167;&#167; 1&#8211;95</span></a></p>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:  right;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<i style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:  left;font-size:24px;" href="" class="fa">&#xf060;</i>
<div  style="padding-top: 44px;">
<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("pub21749_data_02_chapter~01.html");
});
</script>
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try including all the **HTML** files in the same file of the navbar. Enclose each of them in a `<a></a>` tag with an id.
Now if an id is as `id="link1"` use `<a href="#link1">` in your navbar.

Comment: Those html files are very big it is taking 5 mins to load that's why i had breaked them into individual html files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

HTML

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width: 250px;background:  beige;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <h2 class="fm_title" id="toc" style="font-size: 18px;">TABLE OF CONTENTS</h2>
  <p class="toc_noindent" id="fm_2"><a href="Pub21749_data_01_prelims.html#fm2">Sections Affected by 2017 Legislation</a></p>
  <p class="toc_noindent" id="fm_3"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~01.html#fm3">California Legal Guidelines</a></p>
  <p class="toc_center" id="ma_1"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~03.html#main_1"><span class="bold">VEHICLE CODE</span></a></p>
  <p class="toc_noindent" id="ma_2"><a href="pub21749_data_02_chapter~03.html#main_2">    <span class="bold">General Provisions, &#167;&#167; 1&#8211;95</span></a></p>
  </div>

 <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:  right;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;        </span>
 <i style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:  left;font-size:24px;" href=""     class="fa">&#xf060;</i>

<div  style="padding-top: 44px;">
  <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#mySidenav p a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function (data) {$('#nav-placeholder').html(data);},
    error: function (e) {console.log(e);}
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/328968/

The AJAX function looks for a click event on the link, stops it from switching page, then requests the page via AJAX and loads it into the nav-placeholder element.

Comment: @lackshman-kumar : Having seen your note regarding the load time of your pages, in another comment. I'd suggest that if the few pages you have loaded in here take ~5minutes combined, I'd wonder whether the performance of the server they are hosted on, or the size of the files are best-practice. 5 minutes is an absolute age in web-world.